# MVC AJAX form Post for Parent Model & Multiple Child Model List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have one parent model & Multiple child Model List.
In View, there is a partial view for each Child Model. By default, there is one record for each child. Dynamically I want to add More Records in child Model.

I am doing the following Process.

Make Ajax Call with the Form post.

In the controller I Got List of Model (first Time proper).
Second Time when I try to add one more record / Control in child Model it will shows More records in List.

For example,

Parent Model : 
**Company**

Child Model : 
**Partner List & 
Factory Addresses(List)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tloJS.png)
Main View is for Company Model.

Partial Views used for Child models.
Dynamically I am adding And Removing Control in partial View.

For that, I am using Following code

```
function AddPartner() {
        var dataPost = $("#frmCompany").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddPartner", ControllerName.CompanyProfile)',
            data: dataPost,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#divPartner").html(response);
            }
        });
    }



 function RemovePartner(id) {
        if (id >= 1) {
            debugger;
            var dataToPost = $("#frmCompany").serialize();
            dataToPost = dataToPost + "&RowNo=" + id;
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("RemovePartner", ControllerName.CompanyProfile)',
                data: dataToPost,
                cache: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#divPartner").html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

In Controller Following Code I am using

```
public ActionResult AddPartner(List<CompanyPartnerModel> LstCompanyPartnerModel)
        {
           if (LstCompanyPartnerModel== null)
            { LstCompanyPartnerModel= new List<CompanyPartnerModel>(); }

            CompanyPartnerModelobj = new CompanyPartnerModel();
            LstCompanyPartnerModel.Add(obj);
            return PartialView("_Parner", LstCompanyPartnerModel);
        }
```

Same type of code I am using Add Factory Address.

**Problem is,** if one partner & one factory address already there in form. when I am going to add one more partner/Address in controller I get two entities in LstCompanyPartnerModel one has record and one is null.

and In View it will add two Partner instead of One. So total there are 3 textbox for partner in view instead of two.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am working with one View ,two partial view, dynamically I am adding more control in partial view. I have added My code in description.